# By changing the variable in the φ equation to x = cos φ, derive the self adjoint form of the Legendre equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville, legendre-functions

We have 
$$\frac{d}{d\phi}(sin\phi \frac{dP}{d\phi}) + \lambda sin\phi P =0 $$
By changing the variable in the equation to x = cos $\phi$, derive the self adjoint form of the Legendre equation:
$$\frac{d}{dx}((1-x^2)\frac{dP}{dx}) + \lambda P$$

I know that in order to change the variables, $sin(\phi)=\sqrt{1-cos^2(\phi)}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

So we have 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1-x^2} \frac{dP}{dx}) + \lambda \sqrt{1-x^2} P =0 $$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1-x^2} \frac{dP}{dx}) + \lambda P =0 $$
And I don't know where to go from here. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I suppose you didnt apply the chain rule for P: $$\frac  {dP}{d\phi}=\frac  {dP}{dx}\frac  {dx}{d\phi}$$  Evaluate $\frac  {dx}{d\phi}$

Answer (score 2):

Since you have that $x=\cos \phi$ , then :
$$\text { 1) }\frac  {dx}{d\phi}=-\sin \phi$$
$$\frac  {dx}{d\phi}=-\sqrt {1-\cos^2 \phi}=-\sqrt {1-x^2}$$
And also apply chain rule :
$$\text { 2) }\frac  {dP}{d\phi}=\frac  {dP}{dx}\frac  {dx}{d\phi} \text{  ,And ,  }\frac  {d}{d\phi}=\frac  {dx}{d\phi}\frac  {d}{dx}$$
I think you can take it from there.